# Property does not exist on a function's return value of multiple types

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm using typescript to write NodeJS program.

In this program, I import a node module called `ts-md5`, in which there is a function `hashStr()`, it could return a value of `string` or `Int32Array`.

I need to do things like this in my program:

```
Md5.hashStr(str).toUpperCase();
```

However, the compiler complains error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'string | Int32Array'.
```

The program runs successfully. Because it always returns `string` during runtime. But I want to know if there is a way to get rid of this annoying error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a type guard, or a type assertion.

*type guard*

```
let hash = Md5.hashStr(str);
if (typeof hash === 'string') {
    hash = hash.toUpperCase();
}
```

*type assertion*

```
let hash = (<string>Md5.hashStr(str)).toUpperCase();
```

The benefit of the type guard is that it technically safer - because if you ever *did* get something that wasn't a string at runtime, it would still work. The type assertion is simply you overriding the compiler, so it isn't technically as safe, but it is entirely erased and therefore results in the same runtime code you have at the point you have the error.

Comment: Both way works, and the *type guard* way provides a safe solution, in which I can deal with both return types.

Answer (score 2):

`hashStr` is [declared in](https://github.com/cotag/ts-md5/blob/master/dist/md5.d.ts#L2) `ts-md5` typings as

```
static hashStr(str: string, raw?: boolean): string | Int32Array;
```

Looking at [the implementation](https://github.com/cotag/ts-md5/blob/master/src/md5.ts#L421), is seems that it returns `Int32Array` when `raw` is true, and returns `string` otherwise.

Given that declaration, you can't do much better than use type assertion:

```
let hash = (Md5.hashStr(str) as string).toUpperCase()
```

The proper way to express that return type is dependent on the parameter in TypeScript is via [overload declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). Something like this should work:

```
static hashStr(str: string): string;
static hashStr(str: string, raw: false): string;
static hashStr(str: string, raw: true): Int32Array;
static hashStr(str: string, raw: boolean): Int32Array | string;
static hashStr(str: string, raw?: boolean): string | Int32Array {
    // implementation goes here...
}
```

I'd suggest posting an issue with ts-md5 about this.

Comment: Very detailed and helpful explanation. Thanks. I accept another answer because it provides a way in which I can deal with both return types, to avoid runtime error.